# What was the first 3D movie?

Tags: first-appearance, cinema-history, 3d

3D movies have become more common in 2016. Yet the idea of depth in pictures is not new. I came across Hitchcock's version of *[Dial M for Murder](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0046912/)* in 1954, and was surprised to see that there was an original 3D version with Polaroid technologies (StereoVision 3-D).

1954 is quite some time ago already, but was there any examples of 3D prior to that movie?

Comment: Dial M For Murder was released during the tail end of one of Hollywood's attempts to make 3D more popular. It didn't work and 3D was fading fast in popularity at the time so there were few 3D screenings and most people saw the 2D version. So I presume that there were a lot of other 3D movies before it. I also doubt that was the first phase of 3D.

Comment: Note also that just a few short pieces of *Dial M for Murder* are in relief. Also, it seems that 3D was mainly released in the US at the time. When arrived to Europe, it seems there was no 3D shown anymore.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From Wikipedia, excerpt on [3D films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_film#Early_systems_of_stereoscopic_filmmaking_.28pre-1952.29):

> The first 3D feature film was Nat Deverich's 5-reel melodrama *Power of Love* (US '22), starring Terry O'Neil and Barbara Bedford. It premiered at the Ambassador Hotel Theater, Los Angeles, on September 27, 1922.